# How to use truststore.jks & keystore.jks files to build a producer application in .NET using Confluent Kafka

Tags: .net, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have received `truststore.jks` & `keystore.jks` file from a team who manages kafka. We are required to build a producer application in .NET using these .jks files. I have used below commands to convert .jks files to required format as .jks is not compatible with .net applications.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -destkeystore truststore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

openssl pkcs12 -in truststore.p12 -nokeys -out truststore.cer.pem

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12

openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -out keystore.pem

openssl rsa -in keystore.pem -out newrsakeystore.pem
```

Output of above commands are assinged to producer config properties below:

[image: .net code]

After running getting error:

> SSL Handshake failed. client SSL Authentication might be required (see ssl.key.location and ssl.certificate.location)

[image: SSL Error]

Need help to identify what is wrong here which is making SSL handshake failing.

Comment: Are you sure that filepath is correct? Do you actually have a `/KafkaCerts` folder in the root of your filesystem?

Comment: The issue is resolved. I was doing the right thing but the certificates or .jks files which i was having were expired. So, once i got the correct certificates... boom... its worked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. I was doing the right thing but the certificates or .jks files which i was having were expired. So, once i got the correct certificates... boom...SSL Handshake completed and its worked. Use below commands to read the certificate validate and other details:

openssl x509 -in keystore.pem -text